# Can you delete my account and my personal information?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I came across the site from Google yesterday , I seen some good questions on here so i tried to join up because I am a music educator and it was the only way I could see to give information as an answer.
I joined I answered a few questions.
Then had some bizarre interactions where my comments got deleted just for trying to type information in a comment to someone other than the original o.p. that was unusual , next in the bottom portion of the page it was telling me I used too many characters trying to response to another person. All these bizarre restrictions and unnecessary acts of
Censorship then I got a message I cannot respond to questions because it said I did not give proper answers?
So I just want my account banned earned my personal information erased and banned where I cannot return .
The arbitrary and unusual Censorship  and control mechanisms of the logistics of this particular  site do not suit my philosophy  of integrity, dignity respect, honor.
I wish to have no part in whatever this is .
( as these random attributes of dictatorship have no scientific connection to the sharing of information in the specific category I originally wished to partake it
( sharing information about music and music theory ,musicology, and interacting with those involved in music in a free open domain.
Thank you for your time .

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd invite you to reconsider, because you have some answers that are quite good! I remember well how strange everything felt when I first got here; the site didn't seem to operate in the same way as other sites I'd visited, and it seemed that there were a lot of rules for how everything was supposed to be run. But I quickly got into the swing of things, and I really enjoy it here. I think you'd have a lot to offer us if you were to decide to stay!

Comment: This site is like a limerick or a haiku or a 12-bar blues. Certain rules of form are required, and the rules might seem arbitrary, but it's nothing personal, no harm intended.

Comment: I'd also like to invite you to reconsider. I didn't notice much unusually here except that I had to wait a bit to post links. (Probably an anti-bot procedure.)

Comment: I suggest you read [the tour](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour) and some other [posts from the help center](https://music.stackexchange.com/help)! I too think you have much to share, but the site is what it is because of its rules, which may take some time to get used to.

Answer (score 6):

We're sorry to see you go ... Anyway, you can initiate account deletion yourself, by following [this link](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current) which is mentioned in the [Help Center article 'How do I delete my account?'](/help/deleting-account). The community can't help you with this.

Comment: Thank you , I wasn't aware I appreciate that,thanks for the kind comments.

Comment: Yes the site does not operate in the ways I am used to. How have ypu adapted to getting use to it?

Comment: Glorfindel ,I looked at your profile seen broken images like yo have a conversation with you on the topic of 8bit vs 10bit video encoding and specifically using dither and other process to increase the information in 8bit color video ( sorry I know it does not pertain yo this topic )

Comment: I appreciate the responses, thanks I want to give it some time and try to get used to things here .

Comment: @MMJ2020 I got here via Stack Overflow (I'm working in software development) and the other sites in the network. The system (and perhaps even the community) is optimized for objective Q&As without much room for opinions (unless they're backed up with reference). If you don't have such a background, it can take a while to get used to. We totally understand that!

Comment: Thanks my friend

Comment: I had answers deleted simply becuase other didn't read the information  inside or understand  it .( granted it was long winded info contained highly condensed information within)

Comment: I had the polar opposite experience being here short time .

Comment: Hi @MMJ2020 - various of your posts have been downvoted or deleted because they do not meet the standards required by this site. Please fully read and digest our [about], [ask] and [answer] pages. Your posts that are just lists of notes will get flagged as low quality.